# I am getting "illegal character in an array arg"

Tags: tables, arrays, missing

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
{S}=
 \left(\begin{tabular}{1}
&\centering\{B_{M,i}\}\\
&\centering.\\
&\centering.\\
&\centering\{B_{1,i}\}  \{B_{2,i}\}  {.}  {.}  \{B_{M,i}\}
\end{tabular}
\right)
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

When I execute the above code, I am getting the output, but it's stating "illegal character in an array arg".

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  I've edited your post so that code shows up as code by highlighting and hitting cmd/ctrl-k (or clicking the `{}` button).  Thanks for the MWE.

Answer (score 10):

The "illegal character in `array` arg" references the fact that you're using `1` as a column specification which is undefined. You can only use `l`, `r`, `c` or `p{<len>}`. Also, using `tabular` places everything in text mode, which doesn't allow subscript/superscript without being in math mode. There is `array` as a math alternative.

Here's a suggested solution:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\[
  S = \left(\begin{array}{c}
    \{B_{M,i}\} \\
    \vdots \\
    \{B_{1,i}\} \ \{B_{2,i}\} \ \cdots \ \{B_{M,i}\}
  \end{array}\right)
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Happened with me as well. Typed `1` instead of `l`

Answer (score 2):

You may want to double check a TeX tutorial about how tabular and array work.  `tabular` is a text environment, and then would require that you typeset its entries as math with manual `$`.  It looks like you really wanted `array`, which is in math and typesets its entries as math without needing `$`.  The argument to either environment is the specification for each column.  In your case, you have 1 column that you're centering, so `{1}` should be `{c}`, and then you wouldn't need `\centering`.  (Other common options instead of `c` are `l` and `r` for left and right justified.)  If you wanted more columns, then you would separate your columns with the `&` (but don't use it if there's only one column).

As long as you are using amsmath, I would recommend the `pmatrix` environment (the p stands for parentheses):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
S=\begin{pmatrix}
\{B_{M,i}\}\\
\vdots\\
\{B_{1,i}\}  \{B_{2,i}\} \dots \{B_{M,i}\}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

A few other things to note: `{S}` is the same thing as `S`, I've used `\vdots` for vertical dots, and `\dots` for the horizontal dots.  You could consider if you want to space the `\{B_{k,i}\}` out with `\,` or `\` or not.